# C# Application get runs Twice while running as an administrative

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I am trying to run my app from start-up as an administrative. To do so I have written the below code:

```
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
         System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(identity);

         if (principal.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
         {
            Application.Run(new HomePage());
         }
         else
         {
             System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
             startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
             startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
             startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;

             startInfo.Verb = "runas";
             try
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
                 Application.Exit();

             }
             catch
             {
                 return;
             }
             Application.Exit();
         }
      Application.Run(new HomePage());
```

This is my program.cs file. The problem is when I run it it comes with two same application. I have tried many methods but I failed to solve it.

Is it possible to run my app as an admin from start-up without provoking the run as administrative dialogue?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling application.run twice (once Inside the if if you're an administrator, and once after the if/else block) so for an administrator it will run twice.

Just remove the application.run after the if/else or invert your if else to say if not administrator (what you currently have in the else) , don't put an else and leave the application run at the end wich will only be hit if you're not administrator

```
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
     System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(identity);
     // If you're an administrator
     if (principal.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
     {
        // Then run the application (first time)
        Application.Run(new HomePage());
     }
     else
     {
         System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
         startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
         startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
         startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;

         startInfo.Verb = "runas";
         try
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
             Application.Exit();

         }
         catch
         {
             return;
         }
         Application.Exit();
     }
   // you end up here after it ran as an admin, skipping the else and you tell it to run again, either remove that line or invert your condition
  Application.Run(new HomePage());
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion. If i remove Application.Run(new HomePage()); from the bottom , i get one program but my background worker does not works. i also can not debug my program. Your 2nd suggestion gives me same result.

Comment: I solved it. 
startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
this line executes and opens the application. Committed it and worked fine.